# No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'setTitle:forState:'

Tags: objective-c

No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'setTitle:forState:'

When I run the app I find only one error 
and the error is 
 No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'setTitle:forState:'

and here is my code

```
< #import "CardGameViewController.h"
 #import "PlayingCardDeck.h" 

@interface CardGameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *flipslabel;
@property(nonatomic) int flipCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Deck *deck;
@end

@implementation CardGameViewController

-(void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons
{
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
    Card *card = [self.deck drawRandomCard];
    [cardButtons setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
}


- (Deck *)deck
{
if(!_deck) _deck=[[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
return _deck;    
}



- (void)setFlipCount:(int)flipCount
 {

_flipCount = flipCount;
self.flipslabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flips: %d", self. flipCount];

}


- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender
{

sender.selected=!sender.isSelected;
self.flipCount++;
}

@end
```

what do you think the error is ??

Comment: The error is the abuse of the `xcode` tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, and [we close all typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `[cardButtons setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];`, which is calling the method on an NSArray that you created.

What you want is:

```
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop seems off, you're looping over the buttons in the array and trying to set the title of the array, not the button;

```
for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
    Card *card = [self.deck drawRandomCard];
    [cardButtons setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^ should be cardButton
}
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your for loop. You need to reference the variable 'cardButton' in the loop, not the array 'cardButtons'.

So, from this

```
[cardButtons setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

to this:

```
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This is probably just an autocomplete typo you missed.

Answer (score 0):

Original

```
-(void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons
{
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
    Card *card = [self.deck drawRandomCard];
    [cardButtons setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}
```

Fixed - `setTitle:forState` is a `UIButton` method, you're calling it on your `cardButtons` array

```
-(void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons
{
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons){
    Card *card = [self.deck drawRandomCard];
    [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks All I tried it and it works